# decimal to hexadecimal converter WITHOUT dec2hex function in excel

Tags: excel

I did a hex to decimal, but now i need decimal to hex.
I need to build a formula in excel that converts a decimal number to a hexadecimal 
But:
1. Without a function "dec2hex()".
2. And without a "VBA".

Only in excel table.

Thanks,
Hai

Comment: Uhhh.... why?? Those seem like really arbitrary constraints...

Comment: Almost sounds like homework to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the decimal value in **A1**.  In **B1** place:

```
=MOD(A1,16)
```

and copy down.  In **A2** place:

```
=(A1-B1)/16
```

and copy down.  In **C1** place:

```
=CHOOSE(B1+1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"A","B","C","D","E","F")
```

and copy down.  In **D1** enter:

=C1

In **D2** enter:

```
=IF(A2=0,"",C2 & D1)
```

and copy down.  The last visible cell in column **D** is your answer:

[image]

It is obviously better to use Excel's built-in function.

Comment: u have in one fuction?
like row with decimal and ander row with the hex without all that parameters and calculator

Comment: @HaiZone  One function is possible.....but it requires ***VBA***

Comment: hi u can send me the excel 
haim5162@gmail.com
in a file

Comment: it works
but how i take the enswer its the last
but i put all the time anader num so how i take the end? the hex num